# Google compute engine - how many instance should I purchase in order to host two of the website?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to host two website which one is using main domain and another one is using subdomain.

I would like to know how many instance should I purchase in order to host two of the website as mentioned above.

Comment: We do more of programming here.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on the **workload** and **host specifications**.

If you have a static website then i will suggest you to use Google App Engine instead of Google Compute Engine. No doubt in compute engine you have more control over components but you have responsibility to keep things running. In contrast, Google App Engine manages the system for you. So if you have no idea about workload and managment of VM's then you should go with **Google App Engine**.